# Keep element always centered with side text to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need help to structure a page, i thought it was easy but it wasn't, at least not for me.

[image: Example of what i need to accomplish]

Logo: always centered, of course.
Element: For instance, an image, always centered. Image can be vertical or horizontal, but needs to be centered.
Text: Next to the element/image.

There are no boxes really, i saw other questions where they where trying to keep center box always centered, but in this case i just have one main box/container and then text/caption next to the image.

What i cannot do is keeping image centered, because if i add text next to the image, will try to center the whole thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Ya entiendo lo que necesitas... ok, this is no simple task if you’re new to HTML and CSS, but basically you can play with the CSS position attribute of the image and the text; and the top/right/bottom/left attributes of the text. But this brings up a new problem: what if the image does not always have the same dimensions? Well, one thing you can do is to make sure that the logo has a fixed width. I’d suggest to also set the display attribute of the logo to `block` rather than `inline-block`. This will help you keep the image centered.

Comment: Thank your for your response. I'm not "new" to HTML/CSS but i'm not an expert either.
I don't care too much on the logo positioning because Logo will be inside <header> and the Image+Text are inside a <div class="container>.

Header is centered, but then not sure how to keep Image always centered and then float the text next to the image without affecting image position.

I'll try with top/right/bottom/left attr of the text, as you mentioned.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant the image. If the image’s display attribute is set to `inline-block`, then the image will move to the left (as you mentioned in the question). So, if it’s blocked where you want it, you can then try to play around with the text until you get it where you want it. But the first step is to make sure that the image doesn’t move. That’s why I’m saying you should find the position value that best fits your case, which is absolute, I believe. Unfortunately, I’m on my phone right now and I can’t do that for you as I would normally do. Someone else will have to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Horizontal and vertical centering is most easily solved with **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**. Simply set the following on your container:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Note that you'll want a `height` too! I've gone with `100vh` to occupy the full viewport.

To centralise your element at the top just give it `align-self: flex-start`.

From here it's just a matter of having a child which contains both the central item and offset item, both of which need `position: absolute`. The offset item will additionally want `margin-left` equal to the width of the centralised item, but it should only be applied inside of a media query.

To drop the offset item below for mobile screens, you'll want a second media query which adds `margin-top`.

This can be seen in the following (click  `Full page` after `Run code snippet` to see the desktop view).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.inner-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%
}

.center, .off-center {
  position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .off-center {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .off-center {
    margin-top: 50vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Logo</div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="center">Center</div>
    <div class="off-center">Off-center</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! This helped me a lot and thank you for the explanation because i was very interested on learning how and why, so really appreciate that.

One thing: This is not vertically aligning the text to the bottom, i had a vertical-align assigned to the bottom for the text, but now it's not working, any idea how can i solve that?

Thanks again!

Comment: Nice! I like the use of @media queries, that’s a clean solution for the text positioning.

Comment: Oh i just read on the Flexbox that vertical-align does not work using Flex, so i should change it for "align-self:flex-end".