# Adding a character on ANY position of a cell without changing the TD centering text already displayed

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='text-align:center'>
      CENTERED
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to ADD a single character either on the left or on the right of CENTERED, without affecting the x-position of the CENTERED string.
To be clear: NOT on the left of the cell, but on the left of the CENTERED string. And the CENTERED string can be anything, so I do not want to calculate something pixel-perfect and move it by some constant pixel value.
I tried fiddling with position:absolute/relative and padding-left/left but I couldn't find a working solution.
Ideally if it could be build with classes:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='text-align:center'>
      <span class='centeredRegardless'>CENTERED</span>
      <span class='onTheLeftWithoutAffectingThePreviousOne'>*</span>
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then I will need those classes defined :)
Thank you

Comment: Make inline divs and use flex. You do not even need a table

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360225/keep-element-always-centered-with-side-text-to-the-left

Comment: I do need a table because it's way more complicated than this, this is just the stripped-down version ;)

Comment: So perhaps post an image of expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (remove and collapse the border when happy)

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; min-width:20px; }
.left { text-align:left;} 
.right { text-align:right;}
.center { text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">></td>
    <td class="center">
      CENTERED
    </td>
    <td class="left"><</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, I would call this a very smart way to use totally standard elements without over-complicated new stuff. It should work well, and I could have though of it but I didn't :) btw the 'center' class is not defined but it shouldn't be useful since I guess the "left" and "right" will push it to the middle anyway, right?

Comment: Ah, I added .center - but yes, I assumed it might be this simple

Answer (score 0):

If you want some cells to have the extra character and some not you could put the extra character as content in a pseudo element positioned absolutely so it doesn't change the positioning of the actual text at all.

For a left character position is right: 100% and for a character on the right the positioning is left: 100%.

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

td.extraChar::before {
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='text-align:center' class="extraChar">
      <span class='centeredRegardless'>CENTERED</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='text-align:center'>
      <span class='centeredRegardless'>CENTERED</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```